# Java8: change the reference of the variable outside of forEach

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, jvm, java-stream

#### I try to do two things at once：

**1.Sum values from specific field of the objects in a list**

```java
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> doReqQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> boQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
models.forEach(detail -> {
    doReqQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getDoReqQty(), (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
    boQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getBoQty(),  (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
});
```

**2.Filter a object from list**

```java
DoRequestDetailModel originProductRequestDetail = models.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getIsOriginProduct())
    .reduce((a, b) -> {
         throw new IllegalStateException();
    })
    .get();
```

**I would like this code, but it dosen't work:**

```java
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> doReqQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> boQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
DoRequestDetailModel originProductRequestDetail = new DoRequestDetailModel();
models.forEach(detail -> {
     doReqQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getDoReqQty(), (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
     boQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getBoQty(),  (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
     if(detail.getIsOriginProduct()) {
          originProductRequestDetail = detail;
     }
});
```

**The next code could be done**

```java
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> doReqQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> boQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
List<DoRequestDetailModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
models.forEach(detail -> {
    doReqQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getDoReqQty(), (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
    boQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getBoQty(),  (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
    if(detail.getIsOriginProduct()) {
         tempList.add(detail);
    }
});
```

**Is there a better solution ?**

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Note: `(bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2)` could be rewritten to `BigInteger::add`.

Comment: @MCEmperor I think it's good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `AtomicReference` as well:

```
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> doReqQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> boQtySum = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
AtomicReference<DoRequestDetailModel> originProductRequestDetail = new AtomicReference<>(new DoRequestDetailModel());
models.forEach(detail -> {
     doReqQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getDoReqQty(), (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
     boQtySum.accumulateAndGet(detail.getBoQty(),  (bg1, bg2) -> bg1.add(bg2));
     if(detail.getIsOriginProduct()) {
          if(originProductRequestDetail.get()) throw new IllegalStateException();
          originProductRequestDetail.set(detail);
     }
});
```

It's because you're changing a reference of an outside variable in the scope of the function invoked inside `forEach`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) is a related question.

Comment: Thanks, “pass-by-value” helps me

Comment: @Jiumu no problem, consider upvoting the answer;>